# Nginx force revalidate stale cache after timeout

Tags: linux, nginx, cache, lua, openresty

There is a case in Nginx reverse proxy cache usage, when;

```
proxy_cache_background_update on;
proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
```

For the same URL if a single response comes from the upstream with max-age, when all the other responses are no-cache, Nginx is never able to recover from this situation.

Imagine the scenario:

1. Client -> Nginx (MISS) -> Upstream **200** (Cache-Control: no-cache)
2. Client -> Nginx (MISS) -> Upstream **200** (Cache-Control: no-cache)
3. Client -> Nginx (MISS) -> Upstream **200** (Cache-Control: no-cache)
4. Client -> Nginx (MISS) -> Upstream **503** (Cache-Control:
   max-age=10)
5. Client -> Nginx (HIT, **503**, Age: 3)
6. Client -> Nginx (HIT, **503**, Age: 8)
7. Client -> Nginx (STALE, **503**, Age: 13) -> *BG* Upstream **200**
   (Cache-Control: no-cache)
8. Client -> Nginx (STALE, **503**, Age: 18) -> *BG* Upstream **200**
   (Cache-Control: no-cache)
9. Client -> Nginx (STALE, **503**, Age: 23) -> *BG* Upstream **200**
   (Cache-Control: no-cache)
10. ... Client sees **503** for eternity

In the scenario above, an error occured in the upstream once, and returned a max-age (This behavior unfortunately cannot be intervened). Because the real 200 response is no-cache, it is never able to **overwrite** the STALE 503 and forever give the error until manually purged.

Couldn't find anything on the web about this scenario, so here I am asking. How to deal with this. I am using **OpenResty** so both Nginx Open Source modules and Lua is accessible to me.

**Possible solutions and my research:**

- `stale-if-error` and `stale-while-revalidate` extensions of the Cache-Control header does seem to resolve this problem. Unfortunately upstream headers are not open to modification (And there is no way to hackfully insert these before Nginx processes  the headers, as expected).
- Using a Lua script to manually set a timeout for STALE caches, and purge when it is exceeded. But I much rather use a solution if standard/Nginx provides one.
- Add a second reverse proxy to add headers `stale-if-error` and `stale-while-revalidate` by default (I'd rather let the problem to exist, rather than to do this).
- Use Lua to keep track of cache age, than set a variable true if exceeded, than use it in `proxy_cache_bypass` from Nginx. (A bit gray area, execution order would matter with content phase directives)